# Reading strings from file

Tags: c

Ok so, I have the following bit of code in a program I'm making

names.txt contains the following:

```
PersonA.txt
PersonB.txt
PersonC.txt
```

then, In order to store them into an array here's what I'm doing:

```
FILE* fnames;

fnames=fopen("names.txt","r");

nlines=file_lines(fnames);   // function I made to calculate lines (working)

f_array[nlines][29];         // 29 just a ramdom number for the length of person


for(i=0; i < nlines; i++)

{

    fgets(f_array[i], 29, fnames);

    printf("file name: %s\n", f_array[i];

}
```

However the output is just rubish like

```
file name: random letters squares and question marks

file name:  (same)

file name:  (same)
```

I'm not finding the reason for this to happen as the other similar fgets I have 
is working just fine.

////////SOLVED////////

Thank you for the solution, however, there's another small problem now

even though the file names are correctly stored in the array, I can't seem to be able to do this:

```
for(i=0, i < nlines, i++)
    f=fopen(f_array[i], "r");
.
.
.
```

If I switch to f=fopen("PersonA.txt","r") the rest of the code will work fine (doing everything just for this file). My point was to make it work for all the files whose names are in the f_array

Comment: The problem is most likely elsewhere in your program.  What does `file_lines` look like?  Does it reset the file position after it calculates the number of lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the function `file_lines`, you had iterated through the file to calculate the number of lines, the `FILE*` now point to the position at the end of file.

You need to `rewind` of `fseek` to the begin of file to read again.

Place one of those 2 lines before the for loop, or better, at the end of `file_lines` function:

```
fseek(fnames, 0, SEEK_SET); // same as rewind()
rewind(fnames);             // same as fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)
```

If your program has read the file before calling the function `file_lines`,
You need to call this function at the very begin of `file_lines`

```
long original_offset = ftell(fnames);
```

then call this function at the very end of `file_names`

```
fseek(fnames, original_offset, SEEK_SET);
```

Alternatively, you can read the filename while you iterate the first time.

Comment: I think you mean `ftell`, not `ftel`.